# Is there any way to find out that a user is removing an iOS App from device programmatically?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I have a set of contacts that can be synched from my ios app to device address book. When the user deletes the app from the device, I want to remove those contacts from device address book as well. But as far as I know, Apple does not provide a way to find out it programmatically. Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way an app can do something before being removed.

When a user deletes an app from a device the app does not get any notification or additional processing time. It is just terminated immediately with a `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Is there any way to get any kind of notifications to the app in background, so that we can do necessary things before the app get deleted from device?

Comment: @JamesDon As I said, the app will not be notified and it would not get the chance to run any codes before deletion. This is very likely by design and probably difficult to circumvent.

Comment: But when we sync contacts from our mail client(eg: gmail) to device,  we will be able to view the synced contacts in device address book which will be removed from the same, when we delete the mail account. May I know how it's working then....Can't I get something like that implemented in the App? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JamesDon That's because Apple supports contact syncing from various account types in the OS. Apps can't do that.